# Pattern matching and extracting data from a remote machine's output.

Tags: python, linux

Below I am connected to a remote machine and reading (`cat`) a file. The output is something like this:

```
AIMS_PASS=wreretet
ASAPMSTR_PASS=dfdgdg
CREP_PASS=gfhfh
DSS_PASS=dgfhhfh
ELS_PASS=Rdgdh
EXTAPI_PASS=qadgdbbc
```

I need the words before _PASS like AIMS, ASAPMSTR, CREP,..But these are output from the remote server. I know `cut -d _ -f 1` would work if the data is local. How do I apply this command on the output from remote server. Specifically inside the `if loop`.

```
pswd = re.compile(r'\w_PASS\W')
if conn is None:
            print machine +" " + "Successfully Authenticated\n"
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("""python -c 'import os; \
                                                    print os.path.isfile("/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared") \
                                                    '""")
            ret_val =  stdout.read()
            if ret_val:
                print "db.shared file is there!"
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat /a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared")
                data = stdout.read()
                pswd_line = pswd.findall(data)
                if pswd_line:
                    print data
                    <SOMETHING WHICH JUST GIVES ME THE WORD BEFORE '_PASS'>
                    #stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cut -d _ -f 1")
                    #print stdout.read()
                ssh.close()
                break
            else:
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("exit")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what your `data` variable holds:

```
x = "AIMS_PASS=wreretet\nASAPMSTR_PASS=dfdgdg"
[line.split('_PASS')[0] for line in x.split('\n')]
>>> ['AIMS', 'ASAPMSTR']
```

I use the Python [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to first split by new line, then split by `_PASS` and then take the first element.